# Simple table in Realm for Swift 3

Tags: swift, database, sqlite, swift3, realm

I'm a college student with a pretty decent background in Swift 3. My Computer Science club has been given a project to create a simple application for my school's tutorial center. I could code the user interface, and familiar with cocoapods, but what I dont know is storing the user inputs in a well-organized table. I want each tables to be the days. Rows will be each student(Student ID)'s with their inputs like class, time, and dates(columns).
I would prefer using Realm as I've heard many good reviews, but I dont mind learning/reading about SQLite as well or any other third parties out there that anyone recommends. I've tried lookin in Google, but failed to find anything useful. So if anyone has tips on how to or links that has a simple database implementation or examples in an organized table, it would be much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: If you [download the Realm Swift](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/) bundle from the website, it contains a variety of sample apps to demonstrate the API. One of the examples is a grouped table view that would do the sort of thing you're after.

The code is also publicly viewable [on the Realm Cocoa GitHub account](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/GroupedTableView/TableViewController.swift).

Comment: thanks man!! This was very helpful

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck! :)